# Replacing string queries in URL's with Javascript (conditional)

Tags: javascript, query-string

I'm trying to switch back and forth between two different modes in my website. One mode is "Grid" and the other is "List". So in the url it would be www.example.com/index.php?mode=grid and when you click on a specific link it would change the mode to list. My code only takes it from index.php to one of the queries once;

The Javascript:

```
    function gridclick(){
        if(location.href.match(/\?mode=/)){
            var reExp = /mode=\d+/;
            var url = window.location.toString();
            var newUrl = url.replace(reExp, "mode=" + "grid");
        }
        else{


    window.location="index.php?mode=grid";
    }
}

function listclick(){
    if(location.href.match(/\?mode=/)){
        var reExp = /mode=\d+/;
        var url = window.location.toString();
        var newUrl = url.replace(reExp, "mode=" + "list");
    }
    else{
        window.location="index.php?mode=list";
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<img src="images/grid.png" width="18" height="18" alt="Grid view" onClick="gridclick()"/> 
<img src="images/list.png" alt="List view" width="18" height="18" onClick="listclick()"/>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you _do_ something with `newUrl`?

Comment: Yea, you're right @Jeffman. I added `window.location = newUrl;` to both but it wont change after being clicked the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `location.search` to toggle the query parameter and refresh the page. It will also minimize your javascript a ton, see below:

```
function gridclick(){
    location.search = "mode=grid";
}

function listclick(){
  location.search = "mode=list";
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually to make it even more efficient I'd modify your code to the following..

HTML:

```
<img src="images/grid.png" width="18" height="18" alt="Grid view" onClick="toggleView('grid')"/> 
<img src="images/list.png" alt="List view" width="18" height="18" onClick="toggleView('list')"/>
```

And just have one function handling your view toggle.

Javascript:

```
function toggleView(view){
  location.search = "mode=" + view;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't think it could be that simple. Thank you.
How do I have this so it doesn't replace all other queries?